# Extend class and pass all constructor arguments to super

Tags: class, coffeescript

How would you extend a class using CoffeeScript, but have the construction arguments passed to super?

**Eg:**

```
class List extends Array
    # Some other stuff to make it work...

list = new List(1,2,3)

console.log list
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to split this question into two separated; the first for the general passing of constructor arguments to super, the second about the weird behavior of `Array`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class List extends Array
    constructor: ->
        @push arguments...

    toString: ->
        @join('-')
```

---

```
list = new List(1, 2)

list.push(3)

list.toString()
```

**=>**

```
'1-2-3'
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a generic way to pass all arguments to the parent object's constructor, but this does the job for this case :)

Comment: Because Array doesn't have a 'constructor' method, it's not possible.. but yes, it would be nice. =)

Comment: This doesn't work in strict mode, since "arguments" doesn't exist in that case.

Answer (score 24):

In general, this would work without additional code; the parent constructor is used unless expressly overridden:

```
class A
  constructor: ->
    console.log arg for arg in arguments

class B extends A

new B('foo') # output: 'foo'
```

And the problem isn't that Array doesn't have a `constructor` method:

```
coffee> Array.constructor
[Function: Function]
```

The problem is just that `Array` is *just plain weird*. While arrays are "just objects" in principle, in practice they're stored differently. So when you try to apply that constructor to an object that isn't an array (even if it passes the `instanceof Array` test), it doesn't work.

So, you can use Acorn's solution, but then you may run into other problems down the road (especially if you pass a `List` to something that expects a true array). For that reason, I'd recommend implementing `List` as a wrapper around an array instance, rather than trying to use inheritance from a native object type.

While we're on the subject, one **very important clarification**: When you use `super` by itself, that *does* pass all arguments! This behavior is borrowed from Ruby. So

```
class B extends A
  constructor: ->
    super
```

will pass along all arguments to `A`'s constructor, while

```
class B extends A
  constructor: ->
    super()
```

will invoke `A`'s constructor with *no* arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic explanation! `"I'd recommend implementing List as a wrapper around an array instance"` How would you go about doing this? A short example would be much appreciated if you have time!

Comment: Well, I just mean that the constructor would look something like `@arr = Array::slice.call arguments, 0 ` (standard method of converting an arguments method to an object), then you'd implement each of the array methods as simple pass-throughs (e.g. `push: -> @arr.push.apply arr, arguments`, `toString: -> @arr.toString()`, ...), and then finally add your own `List` methods.

Comment: Oh wow, passing through every method individually.. that sounds a little tedious :)

Comment: Well, alternatively, you could just write `@[method] = (=> method.apply @arr, arguments) for method of @arr`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `extends` in CoffeeScript expects the superclass to be in CoffeeScript too. If you're using a non-CS class, e.g. `Array` in the original question, then you may encounter problems.

This solved the general case for me. It's a bit of a hack because it uses `_super` which probably isn't intended to be used in the compiled JS.

```
class MyClass extends SomeJsLib

  constructor: ->
    _super.call @, arg1, arg2
```

Or if you just want to pass thru arguments from the caller:

```
class MyClass extends SomeJsLib

  constructor: ->
    _super.apply @, arguments
```

Answer (score -1):

In my exploration of javascript I required a generic way to create a class with a dynamic number of constructor arguments. As mentioned this won't work for array as far as I know, it will only work for coffee-script style classes.

Calling a specific function with a dynamic number of arguments is easy enough through `.apply`

```
args = [1, 2, 3]
f = measurement.clone

f.apply measurement, args
```

A class can extend a class saved in a variable. As a result we can write a function that returns new sub-classes.

```
classfactory = (f) ->
    class extension extends f
```

Putting it all together we can create a function that returns new sub-classes in which we `apply` arguments to the super class's constructor.

```
classwitharguments = (f, args) ->
    class extension extends f
        constructor: () ->
            extension.__super__.constructor.apply @, args
```

To use this new factory

```
args = [1, 2, 3]
instance = new (classwitharguments Measurement, args)
```

Thoughts? Comments? Suggestions? Limitations I didn't think about? Let me know.